# Problems with a datepicker within a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I'm having a problem with a **datepicker** inside a **modal** (bootstrap3). In the 'show' event of my modal I create an instance of the datepicker and define an initial value, but I cannot change this value after this definition. I believe there is something related to this: https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/978

As a workaround, they ask me to use the shown instead of the show event.

The problem is that it is not convenient for me  "shown" event, as my field will visibly load the data after the field is already loaded on the screen (it is as if the field blinks).

```js
    $('#modal_activity').modal('show');
    let modal_activity = $("#modal_activity");
    $('#activity_start_date').datepicker({
      format: "DD, dd - MM - yyyy",
      language: "pt-BR"
    });
    $('#activity_end_date').datepicker({
      format: "DD, dd - MM - yyyy",
      language: "pt-BR"
    });
     modal_activity.on('show.bs.modal', function () { 
   startStr =  "2020-12-03"
   endStr =  "2020-12-04"
        $('#activity_start_date').datepicker('setDate', moment(startStr, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD - MM - YYYY'));
    $('#activity_end_date').datepicker('setDate',  moment(endStr, 'YYYY-MM-DD').subtract(1, "days").format('DD - MM - YYYY'));});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Ícones -->
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
       <!--datapicker-->
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css"  rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
            <!-- moment js -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/locale/pt-br.min.js" integrity="sha512-1IpxmBdyZx3okPiZ14mzw6+pOGa690uDmcdjqvT310Kwv3NRcjvL/aOtoSprEyvkDdAb7ZtM2um6KrLqLOY97w==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     
 <div id="modal_activity" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              
               <div class="modal-body">
                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="activity_start_date" placeholder="data inicial" required="">

                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="activity_end_date" placeholder="data final" required="">
                              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I see you explained your problem, but what is the question?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing setup during `show.bs.modal`. Do all the setup, *then* open the modal.

Comment: it shouldn't be a problem to call within the show event, but defining it beforehand really gets around the situation. @Ouroborus